# Can markdown code be inserted inside a 'code' cell in Google Colab?

Tags: markdown, google-colaboratory

Let's say you want to use some simple markdown code within a code cell without creating an extra cell just for that little markdown.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

The trick comes from [Colab Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Uzl.png).

[image]

Basically this is the prefix you need

```
#@markdown You can also include Markdown in forms.
```

Another example
[image]

And the code

```
# This a code cell
3**8

# But markdown displays just fine, just on the side of the code itself

#@markdown **This is bold text**

#@markdown `print(3**8)`

# Display an image in a code cell
#@markdown ![Image in a code cell]( https://i.imgur.com/6Z1i8zF.png)


#@markdown [link with title](http://nodeca.github.io/pica/demo/ "title text!")

#@markdown ### Header 3
#@markdown -------------

#@markdown ~~Scratch this~~
```

---

You can make the code non-visible if you want with `{ display-mode: "form" }` at the end of the `#@title` line

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Markdown` class from `IPython.display`

```py
from IPython.display import Markdown
name = 'John'
display(Markdown(f'**{name}** in bold'))
```